# Evidence for the traditional details of Gehinnom?

Tags: reward-punishment, afterlife, gehinnom

I know this question's title is a bit misleading because there is no "Traditional Framework" for Hell, but here's what I'm really asking:

Regarding all the claims and opinions that **are** made about Gehinnom, what exactly are they based on? Even the Talmud says very little (and pretty much everything it does address seems to be subject to disagreement by other Sages), but the little it does say is based upon what? The Torah is more or less silent on the matter, except for certain books in Nach, in which each possible detailed reference to Gehinnom is disputed by some other Commentators. The Rambam is famous for saying that more or less, everything claimed about the Days of Mashiach, and the Afterlife is based on pure opinion. Is Hell included in that statement or is it somehow different. I just find it odd how this mentality of "Hell is worse than the worst possible pain in this world", goes around so unchallenged and is literally accepted like one of the 13 Principles of Faith!?

I welcome all thoughts.